# Tightly coupled directive - Validation needed regarding approach

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Currently in my angularJS project, I am creating a directive for a modal window and there are many different use-cases for this modal. This modal will be used in multiple pages across the site and I was thinking of creating a directive with inherited scope which abstracts most of the logic as well as presentation from the controller.

Here is the problem: I know the way that I am using the directives is not what it is intended for. My directive is tightly coupled with controller and is mainly used to abstract the repetitive logic/presentation concerns from each of the pages.

Are there any alternative approaches that I could follow or is it okay to persist with the current approach?

Update: I am also using dynamic template loading inside the directive to load only the necessary elements. Will I be able to achieve the same if I go in for an alternative approach?

Comment: Why not just use an isolated scope and pass in the required attributes in order to reduce the coupling?

Comment: I am sharing a lot of data to the directive and it seems to me that sending all the varied data to the directive via attributes is not feasible. Also, even if I do use isolated scope, it will not make my directive re-usable since it handles much of the logic and presentation for the modal window.

Comment: How about passing an object as attribute, which contains all the data that you need? Then your directive has logic to parse that object and do something different according to the properties that are set.